# Spring. Bind post method request to base url without trailing slashes

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, request

I have problem which solution might be obvious.

I want to bind both post and get method to application base url. I am using annotated controller witch one of the method looks like :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/*" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public void init(HttpServletRequest request) {
     logger.info("Method: " + request.getMethod());
}
```

And in both cases when i send get or post request i always get result "Method: GET". How can i solve this problem?

It is seems that somewhere in app there is redirection but a can not find any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be helpful to know how you are POSTing to the URL.  What happens if you break it out into two separate RequestMappings, one for POST and one for GET?  Does it work properly then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you test your program, you are only using GET method by entering url in your browser window in order to test POST 
you can create simple html page with content like

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/yourapp/yourEntryPoint" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="data" value="mydata" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and open it in the browser

or use plugin to the browser of your choice (google) "REST services test"

more about Spring MVC 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping

In order to map it to the base url for that controller you do not need to put value= on a method

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/yourEntryPoint")
    public class YourClass {

        @RequestMapping(method =  {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
         public void get() {
            logger.info("Method: " + request.getMethod());
        }

       @RequestMapping(value="/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void getNewForm() {
        logger.info("NewForm" );
    }

    }
```

this will map both request POST and GET to the url

```
http://host:port/yourapp/yourEntryPoint
```

and this will map to GET

```
http://host:port/yourapp/yourEntryPoint/new
```

Comment: I'am using POSTMAN (Chrome plugin) to create GET and POST request. Also test it with curl. And get answer with redirect but as far as i know this redirect come from container (TOMCAT). It is working when i am using something like yourEntryPoint but it is a problem with basic app url http://host:port/yourapp.  POST to http://host:port/yourapp did not work but POST http://host:port/yourapp// works very well. But i want to omit that last slash.